# Return nested array by object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have got an array of object:
And would like to map it to another array witch structure should look like this:

```
const desireOutput = [
  { seq: 0, level: 1, code: '20', value: 'lorem', connectedByCode: [] },
  { seq: 2, level: 1, code: '30A', value: 'lorem', connectedByCode: [      
      { seq: 3, level: 2, code: '30A', value: 'lorem' },
      { seq: 4, level: 2, code: '30A', value: 'lorem' },
      { seq: 5, level: 2, code: '30A', value: 'lorem' }] },
  { seq: 8, level: 1, code: '40', value: 'lorem', connectedByCode: []  },
  { seq: 13, level: 1, code: '50', value: 'lorem', connectedByCode: []  },
  { seq: 15, level: 1, code: '60', value: 'lorem', connectedByCode: []  },
];
```

I was able to manage it by this code:

```js
const array1 = [{
    seq: 0,
    level: 1,
    code: '20',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 2,
    level: 1,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 3,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 4,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 5,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 8,
    level: 1,
    code: '40',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 13,
    level: 1,
    code: '50',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 15,
    level: 1,
    code: '60',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
];
const newTable = array1.filter(i => i.level === 1);
const level2 = array1.filter(i => i.level === 2);

level2.forEach(item => {
  const index = newTable.findIndex(i => i.code === item.code);

  newTable[index].connectedByCode = level2.filter(i => i.code === item.code);
});
```

I don't like that code so much to be honest. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Please note that questions seeking a "better way" to do something are often closed on Stack Overflow, since they are rarely accompanied by objective qualifiers for "better", leading to answers with opinions and changes in formatting; things which do not make for interesting or helpful answers. Instead, quantify what it is you don't like about the code you have, and what it is you want to see in code you get. Or, if you want a full review of your code, check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) of [codereview.se] to see if your question can be made on-topic on that site.

Answer (score 0):

https://playcode.io/963588/

```
const array1 = [{
    seq: 0,
    level: 1,
    code: '20',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 2,
    level: 1,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 3,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 4,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 5,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 8,
    level: 1,
    code: '40',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 13,
    level: 1,
    code: '50',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 15,
    level: 1,
    code: '60',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
];



const newTable = []
const level2 = []
const newTableCodes = []
const level2Codes = []

for(let [index, {level, code}]  of array1.entries()){
    if(level === 1) {
        newTable.push({...array1[index], connectedByCode:[]})
        newTableCodes.push(array1[index]['code'])
    }
    else {
        level2.push(array1[index]) 
        level2Codes.push(array1[index]['code'])
    }
}
// in order to save some iterations. Will only work if newTable code values are unique

const setLevel2 = new Set(level2Codes) // u can ignore this 

for(let [indexNew, valueNew] of newTableCodes.entries()){
    if(!setLevel2.has(valueNew)) continue // this also
    else setLevel2.delete(valueNew) // and this too
    for(let [index2, value2] of level2Codes.entries()){
        if(valueNew === value2) newTable[indexNew]['connectedByCode'].push(level2[index2])
    }
    
}


console.log(newTable)
```

Not sure if this is a much better approach. Atleast is another way to make it, hope it helps.  (Set is a hashlist with no duplicated values)

EDIT : i was watching netflix and this solution came to my mind. only 2 loops,  n time.

```
    const newTable = []
const level2 = {}


for(let [index, {level, code}]  of array1.entries()){
    if(level === 1) {
      newTable.push({...array1[index], connectedByCode:[]})
    }
    else {
      if(level2.hasOwnProperty(code))level2[code] = [...level2[code], array1[index]]
      else level2[code]  = [array1[index]]
    }
}

for(let [index, {code}]  of newTable.entries()){
  if(level2.hasOwnProperty(code)) newTable[index]['connectedByCode'].push(...level2[code])
  
}
```

Here you have: https://playcode.io/964256/

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you don't like or what you want to change in your code.

Do you want to make it faster or more generic ? Or is it just code style?

From what you shared, the code looks fine for me. Anyway, below is an example of how you can reformat your code a bit, see if you like it more or not.

An example:

```js
const isRootItem = item => item.level === 1;
const isConnectedItem = item => item.level === 2;

const allConnectedItems = array1.filter(isConnectedItem);
const getConnectedItems = item => allConnectedItems.filter(connectedItem => connectedItem.code === item.code);

const items = array1
  .filter(isRootItem)
  .map(item => ({ ...item, connectedByCode: getConnectedItems(item) }));
```

Snippet:

```js
const array1 = [{
    seq: 0,
    level: 1,
    code: '20',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 2,
    level: 1,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 3,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 4,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 5,
    level: 2,
    code: '30A',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 8,
    level: 1,
    code: '40',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 13,
    level: 1,
    code: '50',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    seq: 15,
    level: 1,
    code: '60',
    value: 'lorem'
  },
];

const isRootItem = item => item.level === 1;
const isConnectedItem = item => item.level === 2;

const allConnectedItems = array1.filter(isConnectedItem);
const getConnectedItems = item => allConnectedItems.filter(connectedItem => connectedItem.code === item.code);

const items = array1
  .filter(isRootItem)
  .map(item => ({ ...item, connectedByCode: getConnectedItems(item) }));

console.log(items);
```